# Using connection method constructed in other class doesn't work

Tags: php, class, methods, pdo, connection

I have been recently toying with dynamic PDO connection methods. However I run into some problems when I started to use other classes.

Why can't I connect to database in Admin class with method that has been constructed in Server class?

I have tried many solutions. This one seemed most logical to me ...

How do I make it work so that I wouldn't have to construct connection in every class?

```
class Server
{
    private $hostdb = 'blah';
    private $namedb = 'blah';
    private $userdb = 'blah';
    private $passdb = 'blah';

    public static $conn;

    public $errorMessage = 'If you read this text, contact web administrator and tell him about your problem.';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect();
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->hostdb; dbname=$this->namedb", $this->userdb, $this->passdb, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

And the Admin class:

```
class Admin extends User
{

    function someFunction($table)
    {
        try {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";

            //I want to change this line so that my connection would work
            $result = Server::$conn->query($sql);

                        while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
                            //Do something
                        }
                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
            //Show when debugging
            //echo $e->getMessage();
            echo Server::errorMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

I have instantiated both Server, User and Admin class in config.req.php file.

When I changed "Server::$conn->" to "static::$conn->" it still gave me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have instantiated Server at least once in the Request. Otherwise, `connect()` will never be called. Also, `$this->conn` will create a new public instance property. [Static properties need to be set with `static::$conn` or `self::$conn`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

So change your `connect()` method to

```
public function connect()
{
    try {
        self::$conn = new PDO("arguments …"));
        self::$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        self::$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
        // … shortened for brevity
```

On a side note, why not just use [Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064970/php-dependency-injection)? That makes for more maintainable and testable designs, e.g. keep the `$this->conn` and remove all the static stuff instead (in addition to the constructor) for something like

```
class Server
{
    private $hostdb = 'blah';
    private $namedb = 'blah';
    private $userdb = 'blah';
    private $passdb = 'blah';

    private $conn;

    public function getConnection() 
    {
        if (!isset($this->conn)) {
            $this->connect();
        }

        return $this->connection;
    }
```

And then for your Admin class:

```
class Admin extends User
{
    private $server;

    public function __construct(Server $server)
    {
        $this->server = $server;
    } 

    function someFunction($table)
    {
        try {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
            $result = $this->server->getConnection()->query($sql);
```

On another side note:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table"
```

Interpolating strings into a query makes you open to [SQL Injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Use prepared statements instead.