# Danger of Declaring Multiple Database Connections in Public __Constructor vs Static Variable Connection

Tags: php, inheritance, mysqli

I recently started to update my Api code on an Apache server by using more inheritance.  As I was a bit careful to use it in the past due to inexperience.
The thing is I noticed that for each Model instance a new database connection is set.  So I created an alternative connection on a `Static` variable to pass to each Model.  My question is will multiple database connection on each new Model instance cause problems if I create a connection such in my example below using `__construct`?

```php
     class ApiEnterprises {
        protected $db;

        private $table;
        public function __construct(){
            $this->messager = new Messager();
            $this->table = 'enterprisetable';
            $this->db = new \mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERRW, DB_PASSWRW, DB_DBASE);
            if ($this->db === NULL || !$this->db) {
                // set response code
                echo $this->messager->databaseFailed();
            }
        }
    }

    class ApiUsers {
        protected $db;

        private $table;
        public function __construct(){
            $this->messager = new Messager();
            $this->table = 'usertable';
            $this->db = new \mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERRW, DB_PASSWRW, DB_DBASE);
            if ($this->db === NULL || !$this->db) {
                // set response code
                $this->messager->databaseFailed();
            }
        }
   }
```

Alternatively will a `Static` variable be safer?  As I can remove it in the Controller `__destruct` method.

```php
    class Database {
        static $connect;

        protected static function conn() {
             self::$connect = new \mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERRW, DB_PASSWRW, DB_DBASE);
            return self::$connect;
        }
    }

    class ApiUserController extends Database {
        private $user_model;
        private $enterprise_model;
        public $connection;
        public function __construct($data){
            $this->connection =  parent::conn();
            //pass connection to models
            $this->user_model = new ApiUsers($this->connection);
            $this->enterprise_model = new ApiEnterprises($this->connection);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It may be worth looking at dependency injection (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064970/php-dependency-injection for example) and inject the database connection.  This makes testing a lot easier (amongst other things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [IoC container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562752/understanding-ioc-containers-and-dependency-injection), but before you get there you need to design your models in a such a way that they accept the database instance as a parameter in the constructor. This is called dependency injection. All dependant instances are injected into the new object at the time of instantiation.

Since your `Database` is useless I would not recommend to use it, but you should write some database abstraction library or use one that is already available on the web. e.g. [EasyDB](https://github.com/paragonie/easydb)

Here is an example of a single dependency injection:

```
class ApiEnterprises {
    protected $db;
    protected $messager;

    private $table = 'enterprisetable';

    public function __construct(mysqli $db, Messager $messager) {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->messager = $messager;
    }
}

// mysqli connection somewhere at the start of your application
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new \mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERRW, DB_PASSWRW, DB_DBASE);
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

// instantiate the model and pass mysqli as an argument
$enterprise = new ApiEnterprises($mysqli, $messager);
```

Comment: Why do you say the Database class is useless?  Of my two examples the second one uses `dependency injection` as you can clearly see that the connection instance is passed to the Models. `//pass connection to models $this->user_model = new ApiUsers($this->connection);  $this->enterprise_model = new ApiEnterprises($this->connection);`.  Also thank you for your answer as I now know that the second example is the better of the two.

Comment: Yes, your second example uses dependancy injection, but the controller class inherits from database class. Unheritance should happen when a subclass is a specific case of the general case, e.g. Volvo truck inherits from Vehicle. A controller is not a database class so it should not inherit. Also, it looks like your database class doesn't do anything. Remember that mysqli is a class on its own, you don't need to wrap it unless you are going to extend it with additional functionality.